# Wordpress wp_nav_menu code to display child pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the **wp_nav_menu** function I need to achieve the following list structure.

- Page 1

  - page 1 child
  - page 1 child
  - page 1 child
- Page 2

  - page 2 child
  - page 2 child
  - page 2 child
- Page 3

  - page 3 child
  - page 3 child
  - page 3 child

For some reason I cannot work this out and I am sure I have done this successfully in the past.

Any help/snippets would be greatly appreciated.

It's important I use the wp_nav_menu function and not list pages.

Thank you.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

you can use below code:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('depth'           => 1) );
```

and add css code for layout

Comment: This does work however I need to display the child pages too. Could it be by doing something like this:

<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'after' => '<ul><li>Child page</li></ul>' ) ); ?>